# ng-repeat order by string value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I was wondering if it is possible to order by a list based on a string, for e.g.

I want all the `Bear`'s to come first in my ng-repeat based on `item.type`.

**Data:**

```
$scope.Reindeers = [{
    "name": "Vixen",
    "type": "Bear"
},
{
    "name": "Prancer",
    "type": "Dog"
},
{
    "name": "Dancer",
    "type": "Cat"
},
{
    "name": "Rudolph",
    "type": "Bear"
}]
```

**AngularJS e.g.**

```
<div class="weird-reindeers" ng-repeat="Deer in Reindeers | orderBy: 'type == Bear'"></div>
```

Comment: Try: ng-repeat="Deer in Reindeers | orderBy: 'type'". Réf: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Comment: But how does this priorite that `Bears` come first. In some instances of the data, `Bears` are not the most popular type.

Comment: It's not an alphabetic sort on type column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `orderBy` can be a function: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy#orderBy-arguments

Write a function that returns a value used for sorting. The highest priority should return the lowest value:

```
$scope.orderByBears = function(item) {
  switch(item.type) {
    case "Bear":
      return -10;
    /*case "Dog":
      return -5;*/
    default:
      return 0;
  }
}
```

Then use this as your `orderBy` function:

```
<div class="weird-reindeers" ng-repeat="Deer in Reindeers | orderBy: orderByBears"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jnokyfx9/2/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to just use the default alphabetical ordering.

So since bear starts with a b, it's enough to just write:

```
 <div class="weird-reindeers" ng-repeat="Deer in Reindeers | orderBy: 'type'">{{Deer}}</div>
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/nfje5qo2/6/

Answer (score 0):

As your array is stored in key: value manner. This is easy to sort. You need not require to write any further method or function. Just put a pipeline called filter in Angular terms in your HTML as below.

```
<div class="weird-reindeers" ng-repeat="Deer in Reindeers | orderBy: 'type'">{{Deer}}</div>
```